# Difference between launching an application from a keyboard shortcut vs the terminal?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, environment-variables, emacs, appmenu

**What I have observed:**

When I type `emacs` in gnome-terminal, it launches in the same environment, with variables set in `.bashrc`. If I use a keyboard shortcut to the command `emacs`, it opens in an environment that does not have these variables.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a reason for this behaviour?
2. How can I get emacs to open in an environment with settings from `.bashrc`?
3. If I have root access, can I set these variables 'system-wide'?

**Additional background:** I need is to be able to access the variables from within R, as described in a related SO question ([How to access a bash environment variable from within R in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005478/how-to-access-a-bash-environment-variable-from-within-r-in-emacs-ess)), and I also need the path to my texlive distribution for Auctex. The present question is different in that I am more generally interested in the difference between launching emacs from within the terminal and launching emacs from the Applications menu, Gnome-do, or keyboard shortcut that call either `emacs` or `/usr/bin/emacs23 %F`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`~/.bashrc` is usually read for secondary interactive shells after you log in. If you want to initialise your parameters on login the use `~/.profile` instead. To apply you parameters system-wide use `/etc/profile`. It's the first file read by bash.

To make things clearer I think I'd explain a bit more.

- When you login, your login shell reads first the global `/etc/profile`, then `~/.profile` and parameters/variables mentioned there are initialised. However you don't see this shell as terminal because the X-window system GUI is running.
- After login when you open a secondary terminal/terminal-emulator e.g. `gnome-terminal` `~/.bashrc` is read and and the parameters/variables declared in it are available to the secondary terminal only. Note that this secondary terminal is a child process of your login shell.
- When you launch an application from menu, it's executed as a child process of your login shell and it inherits the parameters from it's ancestor process. But `.bashrc` was not available for the main login shell; so it's not available for applications too. So anything in `.bashrc` won't be available for those applications if run from menu. But when you open a `gnome-terminal` and executes command from there, applications are launched as children of `gnome-terminal` and inherits `.bashrc`'s parameters from it.

Comment: This fixes my problem (+1) but doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect the changes.